# Strange acknowledgment in Serge Lang's Linear Algebra

Tags: reference-request, recreational-mathematics, mathematicians

Recently I open this book to look up a certain theorem and saw something
peculiar about the acknowledgments I've never notice before:

> Acknowledgments
>
> I thank Ron Infante and Peter Pappas for assisting with the proof reading 
>   and for useful suggestions and corrections. I also thank Gimli Khazad for 
>   his corrections.
>
> S.L.

The first two seem to be the (real) mathematicians [Ronald P. Infante](https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=7977) and [Peter Chris Pappas](https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=30484)
but the third name is quite suspicious: everything I can find about this name is either related to the famous dwarf from Lord of the Rings or a [small town](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rural_Municipality_of_Gimli) in Canada. What's even more funny is that the surname "Khazad", in the fictional dwarven language created by Tolkien, means "dwarves".

Is Serge Lang thanking Gimli the dwarf? Was he known to make pratical jokes? This is too much of a coincidence.

EDIT:
Here's a [link](https://fit.mta.edu.vn/files/DanhSach/serge-lang-linear-algebra.pdf) to the book. The acknowledgments are after the foreword.

Comment: Please leave a link to a PDF or give us the book name. I'm too darn curious.

Comment: @PranavGupta53535 It's in the title: Serge Lang - Linear Algebra.

Comment: @PranavGupta53535 I added a link. The book is the famous "Linear Algebra".

Comment: In Introduction to linear algebra (http://www.math.nagoya-u.ac.jp/~richard/teaching/f2014/Lin_alg_Lang.pdf ) he also thanks gimli khazad

Comment: Hahah that's funny. I think Gimli Khazad is prolly a very undocumented guy.

Comment: It seems too coincidental to be the name of an actual person. The Bridge at Khazad dum is where Gandalf battles the Balrog and falls. And Khazad dum was the city which housed halls of the dwarves ("...one for dwarf lords in their halls of stone.."). Gimli the dwarf was one of the nine ring bearers. If Lang wrote the book in 1971, The LOR was cult classic amongst hippies and anti-(Vietnam) war protestors, and Lang was very liberal. Just my 2 cents!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Some googling shows that member of the MAA and poet Ayshhyah E. Khazad (1944, Kalamazoo, Michigan) ([aka](https://www.kvcc.edu/archives/documents/TESTING-IN%20PROGRESS%20Publications%20by%20KVCC/Digest/Digest%202009/Digest_10_12_2009.docx)  Asha Khazad, aka Gimli Khazad, born John Pilaar) has a degree in mathematics from Western Michigan University. He [participated](https://scholarworks.wmich.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.com/&httpsredir=1&article=1066&context=western_newsletter) in the Putnam competition in 1964, when he was a sophomore. Lang's book was published in 1966. The material covered there is rather elementary so it seems plausible that he would have been able to proofread Lang's book for him. He might have helped Kenneth Ross too, as another Gimli Khazad is acknowledged [here](https://www.math.ust.hk/~mamsxiong/Math1023/Kenneth%20A.%20Ross-ElementaryAnalysis.pdf).

Comment: This seems to be pretty conclusive, but the coincidental overlaps with The Lord of the Rings are still curious!

Comment: @student Perhaps he choose Gimli as a nickname because he recognised his second name in Lord of the Rings.

Comment: I think you're right. As far as I can track it from Mr. Martinez's post, the name changes happened as follows. John Pilaar to Aysshyah E. Khazad (a pen name for his poetry) to Gimili Khazad. Curious about the first name change (John Pilaar to Aysshyah E. Khazad). But the second could have been inspired by the LOR!

Answer (score 6):

I knew Gimli from Kalamazoo around 1973.  I roomed with him for a while.  I did not know that his name was John Pillar until his father called asking for him by that name.  I told him that he must have the wrong number and then his father said that he goes by the name of Gimli (in a somewhat regretful tone). Gimli told me that started at the University of Chicago at age 15.  When he got there, he said that there so many amazing things going on that he stayed up 2 weeks without sleeping and wound up being hospitalized and given electroshock treatments several times. I recall that said that he was taking medicines which along with the electroshock reduced his abilities to some degree. It sounds like he had a bipolar manic episode.  He actually looked somewhat like his namesake with long hair and a scraggly beard.

He was a very friendly and helpful person, well liked by all.  He used to hang out at the campus Episcopal Center which is where I met him.  He was a well thought of tutor for math and he helped me several times.  He was an avowed communist but thought that his landlord was a great guy. He also ran for local office a few times without success most recently around 2007.

I remember Gimli saying that he said that he was studying cueing.  I believe that he was working on a PhD at that time.